# Texts inside div looking like para

Tags: css

I have texts inside div like below..

CSS

```
<div class="textwidget" style="white-space: nowrap;">

Mortgage basics
Mortgage 101
Glossary
Mortgage cal…

</div>
```

But in my output it looks like--

Output

Mortgage basicsMortgage 101GlossaryMortgage cal

How can i bring back one by one using css

Comment: It seems to be fine when run in http://jsfiddle.net/odryk0nz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre;` instead of `white-space: nowrap;`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5jxum1b/) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a line break , which is [`<br />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

```
<div class="textwidget" style="white-space: nowrap;">

Mortgage basics<br />
Mortgage 101<br />
Glossary<br />
Mortgage cal…

</div>
```

Comment: user3822048 asked:
> How can i bring back one by one **using css**.

not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: pre;` which acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML.

From the documentation,

> pre: Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML

So, use

```
.textwidget{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2gtuubc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
 <div class="textwidget" style="word-wrap:break-word;">

Mortgage basics
Mortgage 101
Glossary
Mortgage cal…

</div>
```

Hope so it helpful to you

Comment: make sure this the css style="word-wrap:break-word;"

Comment: Well is work in my workspace..Dont know the reason but this is the propety for word break.

Comment: The `word-wrap` property allows `long words` to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line. So `word-wrap` is not suitable for OP's requirement. If the word is too long you can use `word-wrap`. So this answer seems to be misunderstanding of the question